# backup PS3 games without jailbreaking

Tags: ps3

i have a a ps3 160 GB, and about 40 games, i have spent alot on them and some of the titles are even purchased twice because of damage. so i was wondering if there is any way of making a backup DVD of my games (maybe using a blue-ray burner) or just copy the whole game to the HDD (there are ISO games available on torrentz which can be downloaded).
please tell me if any of the two solutions will work

also please Don't tell me that "this is illegal" as this is for personal use, i am aware of what i am doing and ready to face the consequences.

Comment: No there isn't.

BluRays are pretty damn strong, especially compared to DVD's. Put them back in the box afterwards and you'll have no issues.

Comment: i store them in box however, the toddlers don't let them last a week hahaha this is the reason i want to store them as a soft copy

Comment: I have a 2 year old, fortunately she can't reach the 5ft high shelf I have for my games :/

Comment: Jailbreaking, and such is offtopic on here. And no, I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

No, you could only buy digital copies or you can store your games in such a way they don't become damaged.